# Single file deployment (pack or bundle) with custom build script

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

.NET supports **Single-File Deployment**, which is able to bundle multiple DLL and json files into single exe file (for Windows).
I don't want to publish using Single-File Deployment, because I have a complicated merge and obfuscation process. I want to publish in a separate batch file.

Is it possible to use .NET's bundling externally? For example:

> dotnet bundle Obfuscated\MyApp.dll System.Management.dll MyApp.runtimeconfig.json
> MyApp.deps.json MyApp.exe

This command will bundle 4 files into **MyApp.exe**.

Comment: I would reconsider the title, so to make it clear you are doing something more than just building the application. Perhaps something "How to do single file deployment of obsfucated app"? or "Single file deployment with custom build script"?